# Firefox Automatically Starts Video Audio In New Web Pages

Tags: sound, firefox, video

I have recently been experiencing a strange and annoying problem.  About a month ago, my Dell Latitude D630 began a new habit of automatically starting up any ad or video-related audio when I open a new web page in Firefox.

For example: say I'm using youtube and open a video; before the page is finished loading or the video has had time to buffer, the video's audio will start. The same thing will happen with any video ads on almost any page I visit;  Where the ads or video would normally require some form of interaction, such as a click, the audio just automatically starts on its own.  If/when this happens, I have no way of pausing or stopping the audio without refreshing the page.  If I do try to play/pause the video or ad, it just starts up another audio track and runs both at the same time.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to disable autoplay. Type 'about:config' in the address bar, search for `media.autoplay.enabled`, and set it to false.